# Postgres JOIN strange behaviour

Tags: postgresql, index, join, performance, postgresql-performance

I'm just starting studying Postgres and I'm in a situation where, depending how I do the JOIN on my tables, the performance and plan output seems really strange.

Those are the table used with their indexes:

```
create table escola
(
    pk_codigo integer not null
        constraint pk_escola
            primary key,
    nome varchar(100),
    municipio varchar(150),
    uf char(2),
    cod_municipio integer,
    uf_id integer default 0 not null
        constraint fk_escola_uf_id
            references tb_uf
)
;

create index idx_escola_uf
    on escola (uf)
;

create index idx_escola_uf_id
    on escola (uf_id)
;

create index idx_multi_escola_uf_pk
    on escola (uf, pk_codigo)
;

create table if not exists candidato
(
    pk_numero_inscricao bigint not null
        constraint candidato_pk
            primary key,
    cod_municipio_residencia integer,
    municipio_residencia varchar(150),
    uf_residencia char(2),
    uf_nascimento char(2),
    situacao_conclusao numeric(1),
    ano_concluiu smallint,
    idade smallint,
    sexo char,
    fk_codigo_escola integer
        constraint fk_candidato_codigo_escola
            references escola,
    uf_prova char(2)
)
;

create index if not exists idx_candidato_codigo_escola
    on candidato (fk_codigo_escola)
;

create table tb_uf
(
    uf varchar(2),
    pk_id serial not null
        constraint tb_uf_pkey
            primary key
)
;

create unique index tb_uf_uf_uindex
    on tb_uf (uf)
;

create unique index tb_uf_pk_id_uindex
    on tb_uf (pk_id)
;
```

And the queries (with plans):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT pk_numero_inscricao, pk_codigo
FROM escola e
  JOIN candidato c
    ON c.fk_codigo_escola = e.pk_codigo
WHERE e.uf = 'RJ'
;
```

Time without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`: 916ms
Plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/M6B

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT pk_numero_inscricao, pk_codigo
FROM escola AS e
  JOIN candidato AS c
    ON c.fk_codigo_escola = e.pk_codigo
  JOIN tb_uf AS u
    ON e.uf_id = u.pk_id
WHERE u.uf = 'RJ'
;
```

Time without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`: 72ms
Plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/E3MR

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT pk_numero_inscricao, pk_codigo
FROM escola AS e
  JOIN candidato AS c
    ON c.fk_codigo_escola = e.pk_codigo
WHERE e.uf_id = 19
;
```

Time without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`: 961ms
Plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/v67V

The weird thing happening for me is that queries 1 and 3 are slower than query 2, although query 2 has an extra join. Does anybody know what might be causing this?

I noticed that `Index Scan` on table `candidato` is a lot slower on queries 1 and 3 also, and that makes no sense for me, since the final result is the same.

Another point is that `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is adding a lot of overhead into the queries.

Thanks in advance! If I need to provide any more information, I can edit this post if needed!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is pretty "searchable" when you notice, that 1st and 3rd query fetch 1.2M rows from `candidato` ...just to exclude 90% of them from the results.

2nd query returns 1 row from `tb_uf`, which forces Nested Loop plan.

This means that planner has wrong assumptions about statistics (expected results count) or costs (of random seek). You could either tune these values:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060926193553.GA27268@oppetid.no

[Have Postgresql query planner use nested loop w/ indices over hash join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66678/have-postgresql-query-planner-use-nested-loop-w-indices-over-hash-join)

or manually force a Nested Loop. Although my intuition tells me it should be better to have Hash Join here.

Not having the data, I'd suggest to try one of:

1. `set enable_mergejoin = off`
2. using CTE to force order of operations, like (3rd query with minimal modifications for easier understanding):

> ```
>  WITH e AS (SELECT * FROM escola WHERE uf_id = 19)
>  SELECT pk_numero_inscricao, pk_codigo
>  FROM e
>    JOIN candidato AS c
>      ON c.fk_codigo_escola = e.pk_codigo
> ```

Comment: But wouldn't Postgres optimiser know better, and chose NesteLoop instead of the MergeJoin if it is significantly faster?

Comment: I see know, maybe the costs settings are making the optimiser think that MergeJoin would be faster by increasing NestedLoop costs, is that it?

Comment: If it only WOULD know... That is why you need to make sure the stats are accurate (data distribution) and the hardware metrics are realistic.

Comment: Try `set enable_mergejoin = off` and read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170975/why-is-the-postgresql-planner-choosing-the-slower-merge-join-instead-of-hash-jo

Comment: Thanks for the help Thomasz! I will look further into the situation. Funny though, your second solution ran much faster than the first, although it uses `Nested Loop`, while when running the original query with `enable_mergesort off` it used `Hash Join`. One thing that is bothering me is that running the query with Explain Analyse took 1 minute and 55s, while only running the query took 460ms

Comment: I'm glad I could help. As for the `explain analyze`, it is normal that runs noticeably slower than the query alone, no need to worry about that.